# Bootstrap 3 background navbar-default using sass

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, navbar

I am using bootstrap-sass for my project and I am having a problem changing my background on the navigation.

I create a myStyle.scss file with

```
// nav bar
$navbar-default-bg: #0056ff;

@import "../public/lib/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

and compile the myStyle.scss and bootstrap.scss using grunt to style.css and bootstrap.css

Unfortunately, this does not change the header color in my app. Checking the css it picks up

```
.navbar-default {
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #f8f8f8 100%);
   background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff 0%, #f8f8f8 100%);
}
```

where it still uses the bootstrap default navbar-default colors (in bootstrap-theme.css). I don't how to change this. I checked the _theme.scss and it gives

```
.navbar-default {
   @include gradient-vertical($start-color: lighten($navbar-default-bg, 10%),  $end-color: $navbar-default-bg);
 ...
 }
```

so it seems it should be picked up automatically...

Could there be anything wrong with my sass settings? I find on the bootstrap-sass page that

bootstrap-sass requires minimum Sass number precision of 10 (default is 5).

::Sass::Script::Number.precision = [10, ::Sass::Script::Number.precision].max

but it is not clear to me where to do this (I am using ubuntu).

any suggestions?

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

adding theme in the include does the trick
    $navbar-default-bg: #0056ff;

```
@import "../public/lib/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
@import "../public/lib/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/theme";
```